# Print DOS EOF (SUB/1A) to file?

Tags: assembly, editor, eof, dos

I need to create a file ending with the standard DOS EOF character that no computer currently uses (It is required for a course).

I have tried CTRL-Z, but today it just deletes the last character input.  Any editor, or method currently available would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
copy /a oldfile.txt newfile.txt
```

This will create a new version of the with a CTRL-Z character at the end, assuming it doesn't already contain one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I did some more research, and I found that Hex editors can do the job.  I have not tried a lot, considering I just posted the question, but I tried [this one](https://hexed.it/) which worked really well.